# How to get dispatch result in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am new to React Native and trying to build an App with login function. Here is the overview of my App.

In my root `app.js`

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login: loginReducer,
    preload: preloadReducer,
});
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <MyNavigator/>
        </Provider>
        );
};
```

In my `LoginScreen.js`, I have

```
import * as authActions from '../store/actions/auth';

const LoginScreen = props => {
    const loginHandler = async () => {
        try {
            // login here
            await dispatch(authActions.login(username, password));

            // I want to get login result and navigate to different screens
            if (alreadyLogin) {
                props.navigation.navigate('MainScreen');
            } else { 
                props.navigation.navigate('StartupScreen'); 
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    return (<View style={styles.login}>
        <Button title='Login' onPress={loginHandler}
    </View>);
}
```

In the `../store/action/auth.js`

```
export const login = (username, password) ={
    return async dispatch => {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const resData = await response.json();
        let results = JSON.parse(resData.results);

        // if login success, I dispatch the token for later use
        if (resData.errno===0){
             dispatch({ type: LOGIN , result: results });
        } else {
             dispatch({ type: RESET , result: null });
        }
    }
}
```

Can I achieve what I want with current structure? I want to get login result and navigate to different screens in my `LoginScreen.js` above. Thank you.

Comment: I think you can just return the result inside your action and save the result to a variable i.e. `const response = await dispatch(authActions.login(...));`?

Comment: Year this looks good, as long as you have thunk in your setup for the async operations inside the actions you are ok. But I see a problem with this an it's that you cant send a notification to the user so they know they are beign authenticated, maybe going back to the regular Promise approach and using the hook useStore() and dispatch a 'SHOW_NOTIFICATION' while waiting wait for a 'LOGIN' dispatch and a 'CLOSE_NOTIFICATION' dispatch to end the flow when the user is beign redirected to the homescreen or notified of an error in his credentials.

Comment: This works, thank you! @nbokmans